# The 'go back' button to cancel a form is not working as indented in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, routes, hyperlink, url-routing

I am trying to create a to-do app in Django by following [this](https://youtu.be/llbtoQTt4qw?t=2765) tutorial. However, things break after creating the 'go back' button at 46 minute mark. Clicking go back gives me the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in djangoProject4.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='tasks']
task/<int:pk>/ [name='task']
task-create/ [name='task-create']
The current path, task-create/“/”, didn’t match any of these.
```

The url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/task-create/“/”` . Which is weird because the code which is suppose to control this link is `<a href = “{% url 'tasks' %}”> go back </a>`.  Clearly this is redirecting to url named 'tasks'. However it is redirecting to `/task-create/"/"`.

If I change the task in `<a href = “{% url 'tasks' %}”> go back </a>` to some absurd string. It says `NoReverseMatch at /task-create/` and even the home page don't load.

I am confused, from where is this `task-create/"/"` coming from? It is certainly not coming from url template.

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/Snimm/todo-app).

Comment: Because of how Django uses folder structure to find files, your todo templates should be within the todo app, not at the root the way you have it now.  So within the todo app you should have a folder called templates, and within that another folder called todo.

Comment: @raphael I have changed settings.py to account for that.  I added "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"], in Templates array. Also if that were the case, no template would load, right? But that is not the case.

Comment: @user541396 you're right. can you share both your views and related urls.py file?

Comment: @enesislam https://github.com/Snimm/todo-app github link

Comment: Your settings.py line, `DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'] ` is saying to look at the root templates folder, ‘templates’, NOT ‘templates/todo’. I’m not sure why other pages load, but perhaps it’s because it’s loading the pages from the views where the paths are explicitly defined as opposed to links in the template.  You can have a root template folder for project wide templates, but the templates for a particular app should be as I described earlier.  Leave the settings.py as is, but put the folder ‘templates/todo’ inside the ‘todo’ folder app.

Comment: @raphael I changed it as you said. https://github.com/Snimm/todo-app-2   However it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of error is that  `“{% url 'tasks' %}”` is surrounded by curly quotes, not straight quotes. Changing it to straight quotes fixes the issue. If anyone know, why did curly quotes changed `'tasks'` to `task-create"/"` please let me know.